# How to create radio button list in windows phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

In windows phone 8 sdk there is not radio button list. I tried searching the internet and tried couple of toolkits like code4fun. I can't find one. How can I implement a radio button in windows phone 8 application?

Comment: what kind of list? Post some snaps

Comment: I am actually trying to implement asp.net equivalent in windows phone. Some thing like this: 

`<asp:RadioButtonList id="RadioButtonList1" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem>Item 1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Item 2</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Item 3</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Item 4</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Item 5</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Item 6</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand this correctly, because as far as I can see `RadioButton` control **does exist** in Windows Phone SDK.

[image]

For Reference :

- MSDN : [RadioButton control design guidelines for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/design/hh202881%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)